# Modifying the end of the section environment, without changing its name

Tags: sectioning, environments

I would like to add certain behavior to the end of an environment (`vspace`). I would like to do so without changing the name of the environment. I found the following code in a different Stackexchange answer, and got it to work:

```
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular\vspace{.25in}}
```

When I try to do the same with `section`, however, I get an error: the command `\endsection` isn’t recognized. I tried numerous workarounds, like defining a new environment `newsection` identical to `section`, which (I thought) should give me an `\endnewsection` command which would evaluate to `\end{section}`. Nothing worked. There seems to be something different about the `section` environment.

Comment: `section` is no environment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters is that space be added if another section (or similar) follows. Hence, it works to add space *before* the heading and that is what LaTeX does. So you just want to increase that spacing.

It is quite possible to add space which will not affect the typesetting of the first section, for example, because TeX knows spacings of many kind. Stretchy spaces, spaces which disappear to nothing or extrude to infinity - these things are its raison d'être.

Here's a baseline for purposes of comparison

[image: baseline]

OK. So that's the default. Now, let's add some spacing before section headings which will not appear before the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{% modified from latex.ltx
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \bigskip % this line added
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\hrule
\section{Later section}
\hrule
\section{Yet another section}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image: modified]

As you can see, this successfully adds space before a section heading if there's stuff before it, but not for the first one, where there is none.

You might like to consider `titlesec` for a user-friendly interface to customising sectional commands. I don't like it personally, but it sells like hot cakes.

Answer (score 1):

This is useless code golfing ;-)

`section` is no environment, it's a command,as such, an `\endsection` is not defined automatically, contrary to a 'real' environment which has been set up with, say, `\newenvironment{foo}`, then `\endfoo` does exist.

It's possible to abuse `LaTeX`'s environment facilities completely by using `\renewenviroment{section}` and omitting the `\endsection` code in the end code of the environment or say `\def\endsection{}`.

Do I recommend this? **NO!!!!!!!!**

### Don't do this!!!!

```
\documentclass{article}



\let\oldsection\section



\begin{document}
Regular sections
\section{Foo}
\hrule
\section{Otherfoo}
\hrule
\renewenvironment{section}{%
  \oldsection%
}{\vspace{.25in}}
\begin{section}{foo}
\end{section}
\hrule
\begin{section}{Otherfoo}
\end{section}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Neither `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` etc. are environments as well.

Comment: The `\hrule` statements are just for showing the spacings

Comment: Is there an alternate solution? Surely “space skipped at the end of a section” is a parameter belonging to `section`, one which I can modify. I found a way to modify the amount of space which precedes a section _header_ —but then it will add space above the first header, which I don’t want.

Comment: Also, is it really true that there is no way to modify `section` without changing its name? I was able to solve my problem by creating a new environment. It is identical to `section` in every way, except for the extra space at the end ... and except that I had to call it `mysection` instead of `section`, which I find ridiculous.

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein You should use space before the heading and after the heading. It isn't needed to add it at the end of a section, so long as it is added before the next section (or subsection or whatever), if there is one. You don't need to use space which will appear no matter what and you don't want to. But TeX has spacing facilities which can deal with that kind of complication - such things are its raison d'être.

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein: You asked for `spacing` after the end of a section. Since `\section` is a command, there is no definite end point of a section, until the next section starts. If you demand bad things you will get bad code. I don't recommend using the environment way!

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein: And you can change `\section` by `\def` or `\renewcommand` or a `\patchcmd` statement.